# What are some good websites to read about the theory behind A-Level (high school) maths?

Tags: proof-explanation, self-learning, online-resources

I am doing my maths A-level*. Often when I am at home I get questions about why we solve certain problem types in a certain way. One example is "why does completing the square work?"

Is there a website which collects explanations like these together for me to read? ***Preferably one that is aimed at A-level students.***

*Roughly equivalent to American AP classes, to give an idea of the level needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Khan Academy,

https://www.khanacademy.org/math

they have this dividsion on grades or topics, i believe they enter in this kinds of small proofs, i understand you are being asked questions about generalizations, and it i think it depends on how hard a topic is to generalize without using further concepts

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here are the sites that I have been using.
As always, Khan Academy is good. Some of the content needed is in Algebra 2, and some of it (differentiation/integration) is in the AP Calculus classes.

ExamSolutions.net: https://www.examsolutions.net

PurpleMath: https://www.purplemath.com/